# In Windows 7 Git Bash, is there a way to explore the directory at the current location?

Tags: shell, windows-7, cmd, git-bash

I would like to explore the folder in the Windows Explorer from the shell. I know a lot of people have been asking to Cmd here from a folder.

I'd like to do just the opposite and open a new window located at the current directory being browsed.

Comment: I think you need to clarify this a little bit, what do you want? Open up a new command line while browsing; or open up a browser while using command line?

Comment: Why don't you just type `ls` and explore :)

Comment: `explorer .` is the answer I seek. Thank you all!

Comment: @GraphicAgenda make an alias for it so you can save some key strokes. I do lsa (as I too use it all the time).

Answer (score 211, accepted):

To open Windows Explorer at the current folder, just enter:

```
explorer .
```

Comment: do you know if I type in `finder .` on a Mac it incur a new finder window?

Comment: Discovered it is `open .` in the terminal

Comment: @GraphicAgenda open will open anything.  You can open PDFs, excel, etc.  Really nice command.

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude I use it open applications, like `open -a [Application Name]`, favorite command

Comment: What if I want to open a folder that is in my current directory?

Comment: I used to use this command a lot, but I don't know why it has stoped working recently and shows the following error message: `bash: explorer: command not found`. Is there some way to fix this?

Comment: It opens "Libraries" regardless which dir git-bash or cmd is in.
@UlyssesAlves explorer.exe is in C:/Windows make sure this dir is in your PATH env variable. This doesn't work in git back

Answer (score 49):

Type `start .` - it will open Windows Explorer at the current location.

The `start` command acts like a double click, so use it to open files too:

```
start index.html
```

Comment: this is weird. I type in "start" alone and it brings up another Cmd window. I like your answer as well.

Comment: Add (.) after start

Comment: `start [anything]` will perform the same action that a double click would perform. I assume it's calling `ShellExecute()`

Answer (score 18):

If you type `cmd` into to Location Bar, Windows will open up a command line within the folder you are browsing.

Comment: This is very helpful. Knowing this will keep me inside git-bash environment longer

Comment: +1 very useful.How to exit from cmd. where can i learn more detail about Gitbash

Comment: This is really awesome!

Comment: `Alt+D` is the shortcut for selecting the Location Bar.

Answer (score 3):

If you're coming from Mac OS X or Linux background, you can also create an alias in your `.bash_profile` to use the open command as you would do on other *nix environments.

Just add the following line to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
alias open="explorer ."
```

Then:

```
~/.bash_profile
```

Then you can use the `open` command to open the current folder.

Answer (score 1):

Windows: explorer .

Mac: open .

Comment: Ubuntu: `xdg-open $(pwd)`